# When I am executing Scenario Outline it is executing multiple times from given statements(Cucumber-JVM)

Tags: cucumber, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

When I am executing Scenario Outline, it is executing multiple times from the start of the scenario outline. I know it will execute multiple times based on the test data, but when if we executing scenario outline it should not execute from give Statement every time, it has to execute the Example Multiple times.
How to solve this issues.

```
@Workflow
Scenario Outline: Perform
   Given I click on Maglink 
   When I Click AllMagLink & Select Exception  on Advanced Filters 
   And I Send the Value After Reading Form ExcelSheet
   And I Click on Search
   And I Click on subregLink
   And I Get The xxxx From xxxx Tab
   Then I Click on <Tabs> and Validate it in AllTasks

   Examples: 
   |Tabs        |
   |Apple       |
   |Mango       |
   | PineApple  |
```

Comment: Scenariooutline will repeat each step for each row of the examples table. That is what it does. There is no such existinh feature to repeat a step of a scenario. What u can try is use a datatable instead of examples. Then iterate the datatable in the stepdef method with necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

A scenario outline is a way to run several scenarios from one written definition. For each example the scenario will be run from the beginning as a single scenario. Between each scenario (each example) everything is reset so that previous scenarios do not affect current ones.

This is how scenario outlines work, and have worked for the last 10 years. They work correctly and that's not going to change. You have just misunderstood how they work.

If you want to write a single scenario that does many different things, then you have to push the code that does this down into your step definitions, so you end up with steps like

```
When 'I do many different things' do
  @results = []
  @results << do_first_thing
  @results << do_second_thing
end

Then "I should see I've done different things" do
  # examine @results
end
```

**NOTE: code above is Ruby**

Answer (score 0):

A `Scenario Outline:` will repeat all the steps in the scenario for each example.
If you want to only repeat the last step for each tab, you'll need to rewrite your scenario:

```
@Workflow
Scenario Outline: Perform
   Given I click on Maglink 
   When I Click AllMagLink & Select Exception  on Advanced Filters 
   And I Send the Value After Reading Form ExcelSheet
   And I Click on Search
   And I Click on subregLink
   And I Get The xxxx From xxxx Tab
   Then I Click on Apple and Validate it in AllTasks
   And I Click on Mango and Validate it in AllTasks
   And I Click on PineApple and Validate it in AllTasks
```

A downside of this could be that if one of the earlier tabs fails, it will skip the next steps (other tabs).